# How to define dynamic setter and getter using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, setter, getter

I've a list of strings, field names, of a class in a loop from resource bundle. I create an object and then using loop i want to set values for that object. For example, for object

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

with parameter param1, I have string "param1" and I somehow want to concate "set" with it like "set"+"param1" and then apply it on f instance as:

```
f.setparam1("value");
```

and same for getter. I know reflection will help but I couldn't manage to do it.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: if you are making setters and getters for everything that ever will exist, it sounds like you should consider making things public.

Comment: even if attributes are public, how can I use reflection so that the strings behave as fields?

Comment: Why implement it yourself? You can use Lombok (http://projectlombok.org/features). Just add `@Getter` annotation to your class and it will generate a getter method for each field (note: it's not source code generation tool).

Comment: Hi,  Please post you Foo class details

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do something like this. You can make this code more generic so that you can use it for looping on fields:

```
Class aClass = f.getClass();
Class[] paramTypes = new Class[1];
paramTypes[0] = String.class; // get the actual param type

String methodName = "set" + fieldName; // fieldName String
Method m = null;
try {
    m = aClass.getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
    nsme.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    String result = (String) m.invoke(f, fieldValue); // field value
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
    iae.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
    ite.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: confirmMsg to be replaced with methodName... It works, thanks alot :)

Comment: hi, Please help me. I need more details.

Answer (score 7):

[Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) does it.

Comment: It is helpful to provide some information about what the linked resources does to answer the question.